# How to show there is at least one inflection point between two critical points?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

The question is a true/false one asking if a function is twice differentiable (everywhere smooth, no corners, vertical tangent), then if there is at least one inflection point between two critical points.

Feel like the answer is yes, but was only able to prove that there is a point in between where $f''(c)=0$ using Rolle's Theorem, but that still doesn't mean it's an inflection point. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Consider constant functions.

Comment: @JohnDouma that's a great point, what if the question is changed to the function *only* has two critical points? Would this be true then?